# How to specify a new path variable in standalone.xml in Wildfly 8.2

Tags: wildfly

I would like to set a new path for some logging handlers that is different from ${jboss.server.log.dir}.

This article: [General configuration concepts - WildFly 8](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/General+configuration+concepts)  talks about how to create the  XML node, but where do I place it within standalone.xml??

I've tried many place in standalone.xml, but all of them fail at server start-up.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `path` element shall be inside `paths` parent element.

```
<paths>
    <path name="example" path="example" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
</paths>
```

You can refer to the config schema for more details `$WILDFLY_HOME/docs/schema/jboss-as-config_2_1.xsd`

However it's better to make updates via a management interface. For example in the web console under Configuration -> General Configurations -> Paths you can add paths.

You could also use CLI to add a path:

```
/paths=my.log.dir:add(relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir", path="my-logs")
```

Comment: And Can I recover this variable from my code? With the @Resource annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't have 50 reputation i can't post as a comment. Using bitnami/wildfly docker, the CLI command proposed as the answer gave me the following error:

Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [("paths" => "my.log.dir")]"

It worked after changing paths to path:

```
/path=my.log.dir:add(relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir", path="my-logs")
```

PS.: Also, Wildfly 10.1.0